# Use VBA to loop through account and send out reminder email separately

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code to loop through each row in the spreadsheet. whenever it meets the if condition, the reminder email will be automatically sent. But in this way, only one same email will be sent with all email address show in "To:". For privacy purpose,

I want the email to be sent to different receiver individually (send the email to one receiver a time). How should I update the loop to do this? Any thoughts?

```
Sub SendReminderMail()

Dim OutLookApp As Object
Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
Dim iCounter As Integer
Dim MailDest As String
Dim NumRows As Integer

Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
NumRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

With OutLookMailItem

MailDest = ""

For iCounter = 1 To NumRows

If MailDest = "" And Cells(iCounter, 6).Offset(0, -2) = "Send Reminder" Then
MailDest = Cells(iCounter, 6).Value
ElseIf MailDest <> "" And Cells(iCounter, 6).Offset(0, -2) = "Send Reminder" Then
MailDest = MailDest & ";" & Cells(iCounter, 6).Value
End If

Next iCounter

.To = MailDest
.CC = CC
.BCC = BCC
.Subject = "FYI"
.Body = "Reminder: Some Message"
.Send



End With

Set OutLookMailItem = Nothing
Set OutLookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not put all the addresses into the .BCC?  It would be private and you wouldn't have the overhead of sending out numerous emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move the part of the code the creates and sends the email into the loop.

```
Sub SendReminderMail()

Dim OutLookApp As Object
Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
Dim iCounter As Integer
Dim MailDest As String
Dim NumRows As Integer

Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
NumRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For iCounter = 1 To NumRows

    MailDest = ""

    If Cells(iCounter, 6).Offset(0, -2) = "Send Reminder" Then
        Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutLookMailItem

            MailDest = Cells(iCounter, 6).Value
            .To = MailDest
            .CC = CC
            .BCC = BCC
            .Subject = "FYI"
            .Body = "Reminder: Some Message"
            .Send
            Set OutLookMailItem = Nothing
        End With

    End If


Next iCounter

Set OutLookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: That will create an email message for every row, not just the ones tagged with "Send Reminder".  You should add the email code into the If statement.

Comment: Thanks, @EvDev . But it gives me the following error "We need to know who to send this to". Any ideas?